# Calculating IoU in Binary Segmentation

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, image-segmentation

i am working on binary segmentation problem in pytorch where my majority class is black (0) which represents the background class but my IoU does not improve .

The function i am using is this

```
from torchmetrics import JaccardIndex
jaccard = JaccardIndex(threshold=0.5, task="binary", average='none').to(device)
```

my IoU metric does not exceed 84% but when i do this

```
from torchmetrics import JaccardIndex
jaccard = JaccardIndex(threshold=0.5, task="binary", average='none', ignore_index=0).to(device)
```

my IoU significantly improves and goes up to 87 and 94

do i ignore the background index as i did ? or do i not ignore it??

edit

im using this code also to calculate dice coeff is as follows

```
            dice_score += (2 * (preds * y).sum()) / (
                (preds + y).sum() + 1e-8
        )
```

it does not exceed 91% , is it correct too??